# which is the relationship between domains (x and k) in FFT?

Tags: matlab, fft

I need to plot an escalar field `f(x,y)` in an interval  `xv= (xmin,xmax)` in `Nx` steps and `yv= (ymin,ymax)` in `Ny` steps. I have the analytic formula of this field in terms of its Fourier transform, lets say F(a,b).

I have trouble sampling F in a correct `kx` / `ky` interval, so when I do `f2=ifft(F)` I can plot it in the `xv` /  `yv` interval. I can't find the correct relationship between `x` and `kx` intervals.

lets make it very simple

if

```
fx= exp(-a*abs(x))
```

whe know its fourier transform is

```
Fk=2*a./(a^2 + k.^2)
```

so, supose i only know Fk and want to recover fx only in the interval `x=0:dx:L`

first **i should sample Fk in a proper interval wich depends on L and dx** (wich i cant figure out ) , then make

```
f2=ifftshift(ifft(Fk))
```

if I plot `plot(x,f2)`, it should be the same as `plot(x,f)`.

here  is my code in matlab:

```
L=10;
dx=0.1;
x=0:dx:L ;
N=length(x);

dk=2*pi/L;
K=dk*(N-1);

k=0:dk:K ;

a=2;
fx= exp(-a*abs(x));
Fk=2*a./(a^2 + k.^2);
f2=fftshift(ifft(Fk));
figure
plot(x,real(f2),'or')
hold on
plot(x,fx)
grid on
```